# Three screens with Nvidia video card and Intel HD graphics?

Tags: nvidia, 14.04, multiple-monitors, intel-graphics

I have a Nvidia video card, but also a built in Intel HD graphics. On windows I can do 3 screens with 2 screens on the nvidia and the third on the Intel card. Is this also possible in Ubuntu? Because Ubuntu doesn't detect the third screen. I have Ubuntu 14.0.

Comment: Can you post your **xorg.conf** pleas?

Comment: @Korkel how to get those?

Comment: In a terminal enter the following: `gksudo gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf`

Comment: What is the Nvidia card?

Comment: @alb3rtano0012 a nvidia GT 430

Comment: @Korkel that file is empty

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here...

```
$ lspci
00:02.0 Display controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF116 [GeForce GTX 550 Ti] (rev a1)
```

Proprietary Nvidia driver 352.63

To work with this config, need to enable xinerama inside xorg.conf and configure both cards.

Unity don't like xinerama, xorg get poor performance. I used openbox to test.

Almost worked:

Removing proprietary nvidia driver, and using nouveau opensource driver, all works, but nouveau is unstable with my card and xorg crash.

Other try:

```
$ xrandr --listproviders 
Providers: number : 2
Provider 0: id: 0x2b3 cap: 0x1, Source Output crtcs: 2 outputs: 4 associated providers: 0 name:NVIDIA-0
Provider 1: id: 0x48 cap: 0x2, Sink Output crtcs: 3 outputs: 6 associated providers: 0 name:Intel
```

then set output

```
$ xrandr --setprovideroutputsource 1 0
$ xrandr --auto
```